# Angular: How to dynamically add components to parent Dashboard component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two components. One is a dashboard of cards (created with **ng generate @angular/material:material-dashboard --name=my-dashboard**) where the cards are created like this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
 <h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>
 <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
   <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
    <mat-card-header>
     <mat-card-title> {{card.title}}
      <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
       <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
       <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
       <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
      </mat-menu>
     </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
      <div>{{ card.content }}</div>
    </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
 </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

And is filled like that:

```
export class DashComponent {
 cards = [
  { title: 'Character', cols: 2, rows: 1, content: '<app-character-sheet></app-character-sheet>' },
  { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
  { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 2 },
  { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
 ];
}
```

I want to fill the cards with different components. But when I went and tried it like you can see above (with the **content** variable), the HTML didn't parse the selector. The card just hat the literal content: .

How can I dynamically fill my cards with components?

Cheers

Comment: `{{x}}` is string interpolation so it ends up getting passed to the html div as a string. You may be able to do this with attribute binding to a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to dynamically insert components, read [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286) article.

Alternative solution is to use structural directives like [ngIf](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif) or [ngSwitchCase](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-ngswitch-directives) for the case where you have limited set of content options:

```
<mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
  <div *ngIf="card.content"><app-character-sheet></app-character-sheet></div>
</mat-card-content>
```

You can unsafely insert HTML without post processing (but it is not recommended):

```
<div [innerHTML]="card.content"></div>
```

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is just plain wrong. Angular does not process the HTML that is added to the template dynamically via `innerHTML`. That solution will get the OP nowhere. Using conditionals if the component set is not too big or doing as the article says are your best bet.

Comment: Narm, I demonstrated `innerHTML` as simplest option.